# Using the Facebook OpenGraph API without web server

Tags: facebook, localhost, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I am trying to understand the `openGraph` API by downloading the `SocialCafe` example (based on a [similar tutorial here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)). I am able to follow most of the steps in theory, but am unable to understand a few aspects:

1. The tutorial mentions that a link to the application is needed - a link such that facebook can issue an `http` `GET` request. If I do not have a web server, can I still run the application? I have seen some tutorials that specify `localhost` here on SO. Is that the route I must take to be able to have the sample source code reside locally on my machine and still be able to run the app on fb? If so, how do I set it up?
2. If I need a web server, is there a way I can turn my own machine into one? If so, how do I go about it?

I am coming from a DSP/C/C++ background and have very little web programming experience. Please do let me know in case some more details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a publicly accessible web server for your development efforts.  You can turn your localhost into one if you can get a static IP address from your ISP (pretty rare now-a-days to get one), then buy a domain name and set DNS up to point to your IP.  On your computer you will need to install and configure a web server to use that IP and domainname combination.  It takes about 48 hours for DNS to propagate the interwebs.

Your best bet it to purchase some web hosting along with a domain name (you're going to need one eventually once your app is out of development).  Then you can run your app under a "sub domain" on your main domain (or in a sub folder on your production domain).

Comment: i guess you are right..  i did buy some hosting alongwith a domain name that i had. need to try and set things up now. thanks much for your reply!!

Comment: BTW, since Facebook teamed with Heroku there is possibility to get hosted newly created application in minutes.